# Laravel - user has many galleries - gallery has many images -> how to insert in DB

Tags: laravel, insert, has-many

User model:

```
public function galleries()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Gallery::class);
}
```

Gallery model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

now inside of my Images controller I would like to write the data to the database.. Tried following code but its not working. (I do not get an error either becuase its called through dropzone... All I see inside dropzone is a X and a bubble with written [object Object]

```
 auth()->user()->galleries()->images()->create([
                'gallery_id' => $gallery->id,
                'filename' => $fileName,
                'filesize' => $filesize,
                'delete' => false,
            ]);
```

how can this be fixed?

EDIT: from the log

the error disappears if I remove the lines above..

```
[2020-03-27 22:52:36] local.ERROR: Unable to find file (). {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotReadableException(code: 0): Unable to find file (). at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\intervention\\image\\src\\Intervention\\Image\\Gd\\Decoder.php:20)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\intervention\\image\\src\\Intervention\\Image\\AbstractDecoder.php(324): Intervention\\Image\\Gd\\Decoder->initFromPath(false)
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\intervention\\image\\src\\Intervention\\Image\\AbstractDriver.php(66): Intervention\\Image\\AbstractDecoder->init(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\intervention\\image\\src\\Intervention\\Image\\ImageManager.php(54): Intervention\\Image\\AbstractDriver->init(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile))
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php(261): Intervention\\Image\\ImageManager->make(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile))
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ImagesController.php(68): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('make', Array)
#5 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\ImagesController->dropzoneStore(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(App\\Gallery))
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('dropzoneStore', Array)
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(225): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\ImagesController), 'dropzoneStore')
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(182): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(76): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(683): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(613): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php(36): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#45 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\galshare\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')
#48 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in `storage/logs/laravel.log`? `[object Object]` comes out when an object is cast to a string.

Comment: thanks! updated the post with the log

Comment: Can you please show the code in `dropzoneStore` method

Comment: be sure to point out on which gallery image you want to create. because gallery is `many` so you need to find one *ex.* `auth()->user()->galleries()->find(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommended:** You have `$gallery_id` so this would be work:

```
//get gallery object
$gallery = auth()->user()->galleries()->findOrFail($gallery->id);

//build image object
$image = new Image;
$image->filename = $fileName;
$image->filesize = $filesize;
$image->delete = false;

//assosiate image to it's gallery
$gallery->images()->save($image);
```

**Easy way:** Insert image normally with gallery_id (This method isn't so good because you don't know if `this_gallery_id` is for `this_authenticated_user` ):

```
$image=Image::create([
            'gallery_id' => $gallery->id,
            'filename' => $fileName,
            'filesize' => $filesize,
            'delete' => false,
        ]);
```

Don't forget to `use App/Image;` in top of the class.

Your code didn't work because when you get `user()->galleries()`, you get all galleries of that user in an object, But you need one gallery to associate with a new image,

Comment: thank you, I renamed my Image class to Photo because it was having a conflict with the Intervention plugin that uses Image as well.. Now, i renamed all my methods, but get `method photos not found in` in the last row (`$gallery->photos()->save($image);`). i do have included App/Photo and there is a method called photos() in there. same for the user()->galleries()... galleries method not found..

Comment: never mind.. had to restart artisan serve... now all works... thank you!

Comment: I’m happy to help ;)